# Problems with multitouch on Android

Tags: android

Per the documentation I came up with the following....

```
public class ZoomActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.textv);
    v.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    CharSequence text="";
    switch(arg1.getAction()){
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN):
        text = "Pointer Down ";
        break;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
        text = "Down Action ";
        break;
    }
    if(arg1.getPointerCount()>1){
      text = text + "Multiple Presses "+arg1.getPointerCount();
    }
    else{
        text = text + "Single Press";
    }
    if(arg1.getHistorySize() > 0){
        text = text + " Previous x is "+arg1.getHistoricalAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X, 0);
    }
    else{
        text = text + " First press";
    }
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
    toast.show();
    return false;
}
}
```

Problem is when I run it on my Device the getPointerCount is always 1. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning false from the overridden onTouch event, which sends the event back to the chain as unhandled. You need to return true, proving that you've handled it yourself. :)

Comment: Tested and tested your derp scenario all return true but I still can't get multiple pointers. Thanks for trying....

Comment: Out of curiosity. What happens if you return true - Because returning false from an overridden event means you've not handled it and it goes back to the chain, no? Just a thought.

Comment: I just saw that too actually let me check

Comment: yup that looks like it was it..... derp BTW change your answer and I will give it to you!

Comment: Just change it so that it truly answers the question (I just don't want to accept something that doesn't have the end all answer. The AndroidManifest partition was non-nessacary.